# Construct a biorthogonal system for a 2 x 2 Hamiltonian with complex eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry-breaking

I am aware of the concept of biorthogonal systems and how to construct them when your Hamiltonian possess a real spectrum. Now, I'm facing the following problem: I wanna calculate the generalized P, PT and CPT operators for a 2x2 Hamiltonian, $H$, in the region of broken PT-symmetry, i.e, complex spectrum. According to [Mostafazadeh](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0209018) there's a simple way to accomplish that, but it involves using a complete biorthogonal basis of $H$ (which has complex spectrum). How could I calculate this base (and even apply the concept of orthogonality) since the Dirac inner-product ins't define, as this is the case? I should have something like

$|x_1\rangle\langle x_1| + |x_2\rangle\langle x_2| = 1,$

where $\{|x_1\rangle, |x_2\rangle\}$ is a biorthogonal basis. But simply calculating the eigenstates of $H$ and $H^\dagger$ doens't seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please take a moment to complete the Tour so you know how this works:   https://physics.stackexchange.com/Tour